# how do we consider sunday as the start of week when applying .dt.week to calculate week number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dayofweek, week-number

**.dt.week** function by default considers monday as start of the week but is there a way to consider **sunday as start of the week**
Example:

```
analysis['week no']=(analysis['Date based Discharge'].dt.week)
```

Output:

```
Date based Discharge   week no
06-10-2019              wk 40
07-10-2019              wk 41
.........               .. ..
```

Desired output:

```
Date based Discharge   week no
06-10-2019              wk 41
07-10-2019              wk 41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simply move each date forward one day before getting the week index?

For example:

```
(analysis['Date based Discharge'] + pd.DateOffset(1)).dt.week
```

I think this should give the desired result.